# Replacing string in a list of strings

Tags: python, string

I have problem with my code. In this example it should print out `The Wind in the Willows`, but it does print **The Wind In The Willows**. I think the problem is that replace function does not execute. I have no idea what's wrong with this code. Please help.

PS. Basic idea of this function is to return title lookalike string with exception (`minor_words`). `Minor_words` should be lower case in a title (despite the case if `minor_words` is the first word in the `title`)

```
def title_case(title, minor_words):
    exc = [x for x in title.lower().split() if x in minor_words.lower().split()]
    for string in exc:
        if title.split().index(string) == 0:
            title = title.title()
        else:
            title = title.title().replace(string, string.lower())
    return title


print (title_case('THE WIND IN THE WILLOWS', 'The In'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you assign to `title` in the loop, you get the value of title is the same as the value assigned to it by the last time through the loop.

I've done this differently. I loop through all the words in the title (not just the exclusions) and title case those that are not excluded.

```
def title_case(title, minor_words):
    """Title case, excluding minor words, but including the first 
    word"""

    exclusions = minor_words.lower().split()
    words = title.split()

    # Loop over the words, replace each word with either the title
    # case (for first word and words not in the exclusions list) 
    # or the lower case (for excluded words)
    for i, word in enumerate(words):
        if i == 0 or word.lower() not in exclusions:
            words[i] = words[i].title()
        else:
            words[i] = words[i].lower()

    title = " ".join(words)
    return title


print (title_case('THE WIND IN THE WILLOWS', 'The In'))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def title_case(title, minor_words):
    # lowercase minor_words and make a set for quicker lookups
    minor_set = set(i for i in minor_words.lower().split())
    # tokenize the title by lowercasing
    tokens = title.lower().split()
    # create a new title by capitalizing words that dont belong to minor_set
    new_title = ' '.join(i if i in minor_set else i.capitalize() for i in tokens)
    # Finally return the capitalized title.
    if len(new_title) > 1:
        return new_title[0].upper() + new_title[1:]
    else:
        # Since its just one char, just uppercase it and return it
        return new_title.upper()
```

Output:

```
>>> print (title_case('THE WIND IN THE WILLOWS', 'The In'))
The Wind in the Willows
```

Comment: This doesn't capitalise "willows"

Comment: I used the capitalize on the whole string, I fixed it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in minor_words.split():
        title = title.replace(x,x.lower())
```

I'm a little confused as to what exactly you are trying to do(its late for me so I can't think) but that will replace all words in `title` that are `minor_words` with a lower case copy. Making the first word capital can be done with `title = title.title()[0]+title[1:]`

Comment: `title.title()` looks wrong. I'd suggest a different variable name

Comment: @cricket_007 it was throwing me off too but its how OP had his code so I left it.